# Build Number in C# file

Tags: c#, build, version

I want to have a build number "hardwired" (compile-time constant) into a class, for example:

```
public class Domain
{
    public string Build { get { return "CONST-BUILD-VERSION-HERE"; } }

    ...
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I think we need more information here, I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Wouldn't you do it just as you've posted?

Comment: The effect of compiling the project must be that the "CONST-BUILD VERSION-HERE" has a new value and is compiled into the binaries with the new constant.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at getting the data out of the [AssemblyInfo.cs](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=c%23+AssemblyInfo&meta=#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=c%23+AssemblyInfo+site%3Astackoverflow.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=a9e938379f07d4dc)?

Comment: That would be the way I would go

Comment: Add this link...Google search results are annoying...http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.4.0/html/d6c3b5e8-00d4-c826-1a73-3cfe637f3827.htm

Comment: As I understand it, what he wants is to get the data _into_ `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

Answer (score 2):

This would have to be done as a pre-build step.

At some point in the past I devised this batch file to do the trick for a C++ project:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
SET CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_CONST=
SET CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_BUILD=
SET CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_FNAME=
SET CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_FILE=build_autoinc.conf
IF NOT "%1"=="" SET CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_FILE=%1
IF NOT EXIST "%CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_FILE%" GOTO noversionfile

:configfromfile
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims== " %%i IN (%CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_FILE%) DO SET %%i=%%j

if "%CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_CONST%"=="" goto noconstname
if "%CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_BUILD%"=="" goto nobuildnum
if "%CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_FNAME%"=="" goto nofilename

echo Auto-incrementing build number in %CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_FNAME%...
SET /A CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_BUILD = %CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_BUILD% + 1
>%CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_FILE% echo CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_CONST=%CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_CONST%
>>%CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_FILE% echo CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_BUILD=%CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_BUILD%
>>%CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_FILE% echo CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_FNAME=%CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_FNAME%
>%CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_FNAME% echo #define %CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_CONST% %CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_BUILD%
goto end

:noconstname
:nobuildnum
echo CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC : error
exit /b 2

:noversionfile
echo CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC : error: version file %CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_FILE% does not exist
exit /b 1

:end
exit /b 0
```

The idea is:

You have a file (build_autoinc.conf) in your sources. This file contains configuration for the specific application (so that the batch file can be reused without changes).

`build_autoinc.conf` looks like this:

```
CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_CONST=VERSION
CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_BUILD=1
CPP_BUILD_AUTOINC_FNAME=version.cpp
```

So when the batch file is run, it creates (overwrites) the file `version.cpp` with the contents:

```
#define VERSION 1
```

and also increments the build number in `build_autoinc.conf`.

You can adapt this to work with a C# project quite easily, and set a pre-build step to run the batch file. A word of warning, however: since `version.cpp` (or your equivalent) is overwritten before each build, the build system will ALWAYS think that since files have changed, a new build has to be made. So you can't, for example, hit "build" to just check if your binary is current and skip the build process if it is.

Comment: This seems closest to what OP wants to do, afai can see.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the builtin version in [AssemblyInfo.cs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556041).  Any class in the assembly will have the same version since they all build together.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

Comment: Don't want to use reflection. Must be a compile-time constant in the CS file.

Comment: Have a prebuild step that generates the code you need, incrementing what's currently in the file to the next value you wish to use.  Brittle, but automated.  See @Jon's answer for the general idea.

Comment: @Bent: Is there a reason it *must* be a compile-time constant?  Reflection is not as slow as people make it out to be - and since this will be a *constant*, you only really need to calculate the build number once and store the value, meaning the overhead will be 0.

Comment: @Bent: and if it's for being able to retrieve the version info from outside of the program, directly from the executable-file, that's what AssemblyInfo.cs and the `FileVersionInfo` class are for

Answer (score 0):

You can get data out of the Assembly Information using Reflection:

Version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx

Others: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h52t681.aspx